# JSP Tomcat and chrome : net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING 200

Tags: java, html, google-chrome, jsp, tomcat

Hi guys I'm developing a web application in jsp with tomcat but I have a strange problem with one of my pages if I display it with chrome.

After the request to the servlet, the page is redirected to the jsp page through the following code:

```
requestDispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher("myPage.jsp");
requestDispatcher.forward(req, resp);
```

Chrome can't open the page and this error appears in the console:

`net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING 200`

with Firefox and Microsoft Edge the page works well

This is the initial part of my jsp page:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; ISO-8859-1;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
    <meta name="

viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<title>Page</title>
</head>
<body style="text-align: center; margin-top: 100px">
<div class="topbar_button">
```

I'm freaking out I can't solve, do you have any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I have already tried to disable ESET's real-time protection. The other solutions in the discussion are php-specific

Comment: I also tried to indicate the buffer on the jsp page, but the result does not change.

Answer (score 1):

Similar issues can also often be resolved by setting the page buffer for the JSP.

```
<%@page buffer="8192kb" autoFlush="true" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved by discovering that:

```
requestDispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher("myPage.jsp");
requestDispatcher.forward(req, resp);
```

and:

```
response.sendRedirect("myPage.jsp");
```

do not interrupt the flow of execution, so it is necessary to insert `return;`